# What are the attribute like names on my ember model?

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember model that has two attributes defined: name and address. If I get a model from the server I can access these with `myVar.get('name')` or `myVar.get('address')` but I've noticed that I also have `myVar.name` and `myVar.address` which are both undefined. What are these and if I set up my model differently would I be able to access my attributes through them?

Comment: Whenever you are accessing an Ember.Object you need to use the provided getters and setters so that Ember knows to update the DOM in the run loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why you're getting `undefined` with the dot notation if the `get` method is returning defined values. But generally, it helps to consistently use `get` and `set` since Ember has computed properties, data binding  and observers. Refactoring can be easier and it also supports the `unknownProperty` handler.

From the doc for [get](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_get):

> This method is usually similar to using object[keyName] or
>   object.keyName, however it supports both computed properties and the
>   unknownProperty handler.
>
> Because get unifies the syntax for accessing all these kinds of
>   properties, it can make many refactorings easier, such as replacing a
>   simple property with a computed property, or vice versa.

From the doc for [set](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_set):

> This method is generally very similar to calling object[key] = value
>   or object.key = value, except that it provides support for computed
>   properties, the unknownProperty() method and property observers.

Comment: Does it matter that I'm using Ember data and creating / populating these models from JSON?

Comment: [DS.Model inherits Em.Object](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/model.js#L26), therefore computed properties, observers, etc. still exist in instances of DS.Model. You should still use `get` and `set` when using Ember Data. Also, JSON is just the format used while fetching data from the server and doesn't really have anything to do with the implementation of the model.

Comment: So it's just some anomaly that I can't use the dot notation for my properties but it hardly matters since I should use `get` and `set` regardless of if it worked?

Comment: Again, I can't explain why the dot notation is not returning values when `get` works. But like most development related problems, I wouldn't say it hardly matters because it'll probably come bite you eventually lol.